# Pandas: Replace blank field only with "Na" in a specific column mixed with float objects and blank strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have this dataframe:**

```
    id      cars  rent  sale
0  123       Kia           2
1  345       Bmw     1     4
2         Mercedes         1
3  345      Ford     1     
4           Audi     2     1
```

I want to fill the blank field only in **the column id with "Na"** and leave the blank fiekd in the others columns(rent/Sale)
Any suggestions please?

**Expected output:**

```
   id      cars  rent  sale
0  123       Kia           2
1  345       Bmw     1     4
2   Na  Mercedes           1
3  345      Ford     1     
4   Na      Audi     2     1
```

Comment: Is `df.id = df.id.astype(str).str.replace("^\s*$", "Na")` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `id` column is mixed with float objects and blank fields, and assume you don't want to change the float objects to strings, you can use `.replace()` with regex, as follows:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].replace(r'^\s*$', 'Na', regex=True)
```

**Explanation:**

Regex `^\s*$` matches for zero or more white space(s) `\s` in the whole strings.  Thus, it matches empty string (zero white space), one space character, two space characters, etc.  It replaces with only one `Na` no matter how many white spaces matched (e.g. won't replace with `NaNa` even with 2 space characters).

`^`   Start of string anchor (together with `$` to signify matching for the whole string)

`\s`  White space

`*`   Zero or more repetition of the character preceding it (`\s`).

`$`   End of string anchor

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    id      cars rent sale
0  123       Kia         2
1  345       Bmw    1    4
2   Na  Mercedes         1
3  345      Ford    1     
4   Na      Audi    2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df.id = df.id.replace("", "Na")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id      cars rent sale
0  123       Kia         2
1  345       Bmw    1    4
2   Na  Mercedes         1
3  345      Ford    1     
4   Na      Audi    2    1
```

---

EDIT: If empty cells aren't `""` strings:

```py
df.id = df.id.apply(lambda x: x if x.strip() else "Na")
print(df)
```

Comment: @AhmedChater Make sure the empty cells are really `""` strings.

Comment: Actually it's a float object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
df['id'] = df.where(~(df['id'] == ''), other='Na')
```

From documentation:

> Where ***cond*** is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from ***other***

***Edit:*** If `id` column is not `""`, then

```
df['id'] = df.where(~(df['id'].str.strip() == ''), other='Na')
```

Comment: I have a float object so i can't use strip